# How to filter TOP 1 condition in WHERE clause

Tags: sql-server, performance, t-sql, sql-server-2012

What would be the most efficient way to eliminate records in `WHERE` clause using `TOP 1` logic?

Table `tblQuoteStatusChangeLog` is not in a `JOIN`. 
But based on value in this table I need to eliminate records that have `NewQuoteStatusID` = 12

It works the way it is, but I am looking for more efficient way, since I have Sort (Top N Sort) operator that is too expansive.

```
SELECT    
    Q.ControlNo   
    ,sum(fid.amtbilled) as Premium


FROM           
    [dbo].tblQuotes Q 
        inner join [dbo].[tblFin_Invoices] FI  on Q.QuoteID = FI.QuoteID and FI.failed = 0  
        inner join [dbo].[tblFin_InvoiceDetails] FID  on FI.[InvoiceNum] = FID.InvoiceNum  
WHERE       (
            SELECT  TOP 1 NewQuoteStatusID
             FROM    tblQuoteStatusChangeLog
             WHERE   (ControlNo = Q.ControlNo)
             ORDER BY Timestamp DESC
             ) <> 12

Group by
Q.ControlNo
```

[image]

Comment: There is no possible way you can do this without sorting, not technically, but also not logically. How are you going to find the latest record if you can't sort?

Comment: a better sample would give us a better logic understanding. However, `tblQuoteStatusChangeLog` you could change the sort of the index to DESC, so the records will be always sorted DESC, which will remove the need of using `ORDER BY Timestamp DESC` I usually do that with the PK clustered index, and sometimes I do it on the non-clustered index. depends on the table's data.

Comment: You can try using `FirstValue` instead of `TOP 1` but it will still require an `order by` clause.

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: The text of your question says "I need to eliminate records that have `NewQuoteStatusID = 12`", but the logic in your query says you're eliminating _the most recent_ `NewQuoteStatusID = 12`. Which is correct? If it's _any_ `NewQuoteStatusID = 12`, there's room for improvement. If it's _most recent_, your stuck with a sort.

Comment: "too expensive" by what criteria?  How long does this query take to run, and how frequently do you run it?  Part of good optimization is knowing how to pick your battles.

Comment: What indexes do you have on `tblQuoteStatusChangeLog`? A [covering index](http://www.dbadiaries.com/sql-server-covering-index-and-key-lookup/) on `ControlNo`, `Timestamp desc` (in that order) and [including](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190806.aspx) `NewQuoteStatusID` may help.

Comment: Tip: Please see [paste the plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/instructions/) for a better way to include an execution plan in your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is [RBAR](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic642789-338-1.aspx); performing the same subquery 1 at a time, which is very inefficient.

You worry about "sort", but that by itself would not be a problem. Look further up and left of the plan; to the nested loop. See the fat input line at the top and thin just below. Basically you're hitting your sort very many times.

Suggestion: try to use a set-based solution. "Prepare" the data you require for the WHERE clause "in advance", so you can eliminate the RBAR. Imagine you had `LatestStatus` as a table with `ControlNo` and `StatusID` columns. It would be much simpler to apply your filter; and the Query Optimiser should be able to find a more efficient overall plan.

You can set this up using a CTE.

```
;with StatusByControlNo as (
  SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ControlNo ORDER BY Timestamp DESC) AS RowNo,
          ControlNo, Timestamp, NewQuoteStatusID
  FROM    tblQuoteStatusChangeLog
) ...
/*Easy to get Latest status per ControlNo from here*/
SELECT  ControlNo, NewQuoteStatusID
FROM    StatusByControlNo
WHERE   RowNo = 1
```

Now with a few tweaks your query becomes:

```
;with StatusByControlNo as (
  SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ControlNo ORDER BY Timestamp DESC) AS RowNo,
          ControlNo, Timestamp, NewQuoteStatusID
  FROM    tblQuoteStatusChangeLog
)
SELECT    
    Q.ControlNo,
    sum(fid.amtbilled) as Premium
FROM           
    tblQuotes Q 
    inner join tblFin_Invoices FI
        on Q.QuoteID = FI.QuoteID and FI.failed = 0
    inner join tblFin_InvoiceDetails FID
        on FI.InvoiceNum = FID.InvoiceNum
    inner join StatusByControlNo S
        on S.ControlNo = Q.ControlNo and S.RowNo = 1
WHERE
    S.ControlNo <> 12
Group by Q.ControlNo
```

It should go without saying you could try a number of variations on this. But the core principle is to reduce RBAR and look for solutions that are more 'set-based'.

Comment: PS: My answer focuses on how to change the query based on the evident RBAR problem. But in general, to maximise performance improvement potential one should always consider both the query and the table indexes.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you